# Stripe/NodeJS: Passing an empty string for promotion_code

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

When creating a subscription, if the user does not enter a promotion_code the code fails with error:

```
You passed an empty string for 'promotion_code'. We assume empty values are an attempt to unset a parameter; however 'promotion_code' cannot be unset. You should remove 'promotion_code' from your request or supply a non-empty value.
```

promo is taken from the front end (otherwise it is a blank value). I tried using an if else statement wrapped around promotion_code which also failed - how can I either pass a null or blank value to this, or omit this line if a promotion code is not entered?

```
const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
                customer: customer.id,
                items: [{ price: "price_1N1TKrGxUje7SlyIeNldQvLT" }],
                payment_settings: {
                  payment_method_options: {
                    card: {
                      request_three_d_secure: "any",
                    },
                  },
                  payment_method_types: ["card"],
                  save_default_payment_method: "on_subscription",
                },
                promotion_code: promo,
                expand: ["latest_invoice.payment_intent"],
              });
```

Comment: have the params object outside without promotion code. then do an `if (promo)` and inside set `params.promotion_code=promo`. then after that await stripe.sub.create(params)

Comment: Can you provide a sample of how to do this?

Comment: lets say what you are passing to the create is the params object. so create `const params = {all fields except promotion_code}`. then do `if (promo) params.promotion_code = promo` then do `const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create(params)`

Answer (score 0):

As @cmgchess "have the params object outside without promotion code. then do an if (promo) and inside set params.promotion_code=promo. then after that await stripe.sub.create(params)"